# Using a raw expresion inside a one of many relationship?

Tags: laravel

I have this relationship which gets the latested sorted item:

```
    public function mediaGalleryLatest(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->media()->one()->ofMany([
            'sort' => 'min',
        ], fn (Builder $query) => $query->whereCollection('gallery'));
    }
```

Unfortunately, `sort` can have `null` values, which breaks the above. I want `null` values to be considered in the `sort` but come last.

I normally do this with:

```
 ->orderByRaw('ISNULL(sort), sort ASC');
```

But how can I apply this to a one of many relationship?

Comment: just asking for clarity, is there an issue doing it like this `$query->whereCollection('gallery')->orderByDesc('sort')->orderByRaw('ISNULL(sort), sort ASC');`? I am a little confused at to what's the ask here

Comment: That's not a relationship.

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-tap)?

Comment: No, the question is quite clear, i'm looking for a on of many relationship

Comment: Why are you not using `latestOfMany()` ? https://laravel-news.com/one-of-many-eloquent-relationship